# Post List Widget with custom posts and editing the Read More Link

Tags: posts, widgets, links, excerpt

I actually have 2 questions, one related to the Post List Widget, the other concerns the "Read More"-link.

***ad 1)*** I want to show a certain category of posts (only one post at a time) in this widget. I know there's a "Show Post" widget as well, but it returns an error for whatever reason, so I settled on the Post List Widget. **How can I make the Post List Widget show only posts from a certain category, in excerpt-format.**

***ad 2)*** So I have an excerpt of a post now and **want to change the "Read More"-link or rather the text.** I found this on a site related to the topic:

```
function et_excerpt_more($more) {
global $post;
return '<div class="view-full-post"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" 
class="view-full-post-btn">View Full Post</a></div>;';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'et_excerpt_more');
```

But it doesn't seem to apply to the widget. Here's what the widget looks like code-wise on the site:

```
<aside id="pcs-list-widget-2" class="widget clearfix pcs-list-widget">
<h3 class="widget-title">
<ul class="post-list with-excerpt with-image">
<li class="listed-post">
<div class="pcs-excerpt-wrapper">
<img class="pcs-featured-image wp-post-image" alt="Weinberge bei Dürnstein, Wachau" src="http://www.wein-partner.at/wp/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/fotolia_66064320-300x200.jpg">
<div class="pcs-excerpt">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</p>
<p>
<span class="read-more">
<a title="Test-News" href="http://www.wein-partner.at/wp/test-news/">Read more</a>
</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</aside>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but third party plugins are off topic here. You should contact the plugin author. Also note that we have a one question per post policy. Asking more than one question can lead to your question being closed as too broad :-)

Comment: My problem is that I don't know if it is in fact a plugin or not. If it is, I have no idea which one :P

Comment: Then you should debug the issue. Turn debug on, switch to a bundled theme then turn of one plugin at a time an check when the error goes away

Comment: so debug the "single post widget"?

Comment: nevermind. Found out it's the "Custom Content Shortcode" plugin